# Windows 8.1 app swipe up opens appbar and swip up closes appbar - is this default behavior?

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

I have a bottom appBar in a Windows 8.1 app.
When I swipe up the bottom appBar opens.  Good.
If I swipe down towards the bottom appBar nothing happens. Not Good.
If I swipe up again the bottom appBar closes. Not good.

I would like it to swipe up = opens bottom AppBar and swipe down = close bottom AppBar.

I have put an eventhandler on the AppBar, Grid within the appBar to capture a pointer entered event but i am pretty sure that isn't the proper way to control it.

The one thing that might be the culprit is we have set IsSticky = true because we want to have only the swipe at the bottom edge of the screen.

I have put up a video of the behavior here:  [Click here for video of behavior](http://tinypic.com/r/27zc9dt/8)

Is there a way with isSticky=true to control swipe up = open and swipe down = close?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is the default behavior. By default, app bars are dismissed when the user interacts with your app anywhere outside of the app bar. This is called light dismiss. To keep commands visible, you can change the dismissal mode by setting the IsSticky property to true. When an app bar is sticky, it's dismissed only when the user right-clicks, presses Windows+Z, or swipes from the top or bottom edge of the screen.

For Example:

```
<AppBar IsSticky="True">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <Button Style="{StaticResource HelpAppBarButtonStyle}" 
            Click="Button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</AppBar>
```

Appbars can be dismissed by the user with an edge swipe. App bars automatically respond to the edge swipe. So there is no way to dismiss the appbar on swipe down, so you have to do it programmatically for your need.

Comment: Thanks Utsav. I thought that i'd have to do it by code. It didn't hit me until i thought about the definition of IsSticky. 
Thanks for your quick response!